# Master Theorem: How to find the value of b in this recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence, master-theorem

The master theorem is used with recurrences of the form `T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)` where a >=1 and b > 1, in which case the value of b is can be easily seen from the recurrence, however I have a recurrence of the form

```
T(n) = T((n/4)+3) + f(n)
```

How do I get b?

Comment: This may be a better fit for the [computer science stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/master-theorem)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on the cs site linked in the comment above.

Comment: I will repost there, but what qualifies a particular question as suitable for cs stack exchange versus here?

Comment: The site is specifically for programing. For it to be a good fit for this site you would need to know how to solve the problem already, just only having a question about the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0):

So if you try to simplify the recurrence it will be like this,
T(n)= T((n+12)/3)) + f(n)

since there is something adding with n every time so there are two possibilities,
either master theorem will not apply as the equation is not in the form T(n)=aT(n/b)+ f(n)
or you can ignore the +12 as is is the constant and is not changing when n is changing
so you can rewrite it as T(n)= T(n/3)+f(n) and solve this with master theorem and the answer you will find will most likely be the same for the upper one.

OR you can simple guess the solution by using the recursion tree